# Firebase connections between data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to create connections using Firebase Realtime Database?

For example, like this:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bob"
      }
   ],
   "projects":[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Title",
        "userId": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

And after there i want to get all projects which specific user has,
how to to that?

Comment: The answer, strangely enough, is outlined in the Firebase getting started guides and example projects. Take a look at [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) and move on to [Working with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data). After that thoroughly read [How To Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then write some code and when you get stuck with that code, post it and we will try to help!

Answer (score 0):

According to Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) (chapter: Best practices for data structure) your data structure in Fb database could be like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "user01": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bob"
        }
    },
    "projects": {
        "proj01": {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Title",
            "userId": "user01"
        }
    },
    "usersProjects": {
        "user01": {
            "proj01": true
        }
    }
}
```

This example avoids storing arrays in Fb (recommended approach). The "id" field is not necessary because Firebase will create unique ID every time you add data to collection. But in some cases you want to have your own ID.